# Stretch a svg circle in html

Tags: html, css, svg, vector

I'm trying to animate a circle to transform into a line. My problem is that the cricle turns into an oval once i stretch it, however i want it to be a straight line that is just rounded at the ends. how do i change that?

```css
svg { 
  background: white;
  border: 1px dotted #3983ab;
  width: 96%;
  height: 1000px;
  }
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Ebene_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 xml:space="preserve">
 
 <g>
<circle cx="100" cy="100" r="80" fill="red">
  
 <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
  type="scale"
  from="1 1"
  to="10 1"
  begin="mouseover"
  dur="1s"
  repeatCount="1"
/>
  </circle>
 </g>      
</svg>
```

Comment: I wouldn't start with a circle. I'd start with a path with rounded ends that has no length...if you follow me.

Comment: Sort of like - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/EEQQzw

Comment: Good idea to start, thank you, managed to do it like that now:https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xWYjyw
however still have a little problem with the Viewbox like that. whenever I make the box bigger the circle also gets bigger, how do i prevent this?

Comment: You'd have to change the x1/x2 co-ordinates at the same time I'd guess

Comment: https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/bvLzmP